# Integration of Slack within Teams help center has wrong directions

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

Consider:

https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000053145-how-to-integrate-your-team-with-slack

You should not click Billing & Account when trying to integrate [Slack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_(software)) with SO Teams. This help page should be fixed.

Namely:

> Admins: Navigate to your team account and click 'Settings' from here,
>   under 'General Settings', click 'Billing & Account'

Comment: Is it an idea to combine all these (seemingly) typo's in a single post?

Comment: @AndréKool *flagged as too broad* =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has now been resolved.